# Schanuel's Lemma in Rotman book

Tags: homological-algebra

The statement is:

> Given exact sequences $0\rightarrow K\overset{i}{\rightarrow} P\overset{\pi}{\rightarrow} M\rightarrow 0 $ and $0\rightarrow K'\overset{i'}{\rightarrow} P'\overset{\pi'}{\rightarrow} M\rightarrow 0$ where $P$ and $P'$ are projective, then there is an isomorphism $K\oplus P' \cong K'\oplus P$.

I think the proof is wrong. It said that $\psi: P\oplus K' \to P'$ with $\psi(u,x') =\beta({u})-i'(x')$ being surjective. I can not check it by myself. Can you help explain it more? I do see the proof in Wikipedia and it is easy to understand but in the other way.

Comment: I have not checked if your claim is correct or not, but Rotman has made available an errata for his book, which you may check.

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff This statement is correct, and the very same proof appears in many textbooks (yet none of them writes out all the diagram chasing).

Comment: @Alejo Good. ${}$

Answer (score 7):

It would be nice of you to define the involved morphisms in your post. So we consider a diagram with exact rows
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> K @>i>> P @>\pi>> M @>>> 0 \\
@. @VV\alpha V @VV\beta V @VV\mathrm{id}_M V @. \\
0 @>>> K' @>>i'> P' @>>\pi'> M @>>> 0
\end{CD}
$$

Here $\beta$ exists by the definition of $P$ being projective, and $\alpha$ is the canonical morphism induced by $\beta$ on the kernels (the restriction to the kernels). Rotman considers then a sequence
$$\tag{*} 0 \to K \xrightarrow{\begin{pmatrix}i\\ \alpha\end{pmatrix}} P\oplus K' \xrightarrow{(\beta, -i')} P' \to 0$$
and claims it is exact. It is really some diagram chasing, but let me write down everything, since you are asking about it.

- ${i\choose \alpha}$ is injective simply because $i$ is injective.
- $(\beta, -i')$ is surjective. For an element $p' \in P'$ we consider $m = \pi' (p')\in M$. Since $\pi$ is surjective, there exists $p\in P$ such that $\pi (p) = m$. We have now
  $$\pi' \beta (p) = \pi (p) = m = \pi' (p').$$
  That is, $\pi' (\beta (p) - p') = 0$. The kernel of $\pi'$ is $i'$, so there exists some $k'\in K'$ such that $\beta (p) - p' = i' (k')$. Now
  $p' = \beta (p) - i' (k')$.
- $\operatorname{im} {i\choose \alpha} \subseteq \ker (\beta,-i')$ because the composition of the two arrows is
  $$(\beta,-i')\circ {i\choose \alpha} = \beta\circ i - i'\circ \alpha,$$
  which is zero by the commutativity of the left square.
- Finally, to see that $\ker (\beta,-i') \subseteq \operatorname{im} {i\choose \alpha}$, consider an element $(p,k') \in P\oplus K'$ such that $\beta (p) - i' (k') = 0$. We have by the commutativity of the second square
  $$\pi (p) = \pi' \beta (p) = \pi' i' (k') = 0.$$
  So $p \in \ker \pi$, i.e. $p = i (k)$ for some $k\in K$. Then, by the commutativity of the first square,
  $$i' \alpha (k) = \beta i (k) = \beta (p) = i' (k').$$
  Since $i'$ is mono, this implies $k' = \alpha (k)$. So we succeeded in showing that $(p,k') = (i (k), \alpha (k))$ for some $k\in K$.

The exactness of ( * ) implies $K\oplus P'\cong P'\oplus K'$, since $P'$ is projective and hence ( * ) splits.

---

I checked the [proof in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_lemma) that you mention, and it is indeed slightly different: it considers the pullback of the arrows $\pi$ and $\pi'$. Let me write down that argument without using elements.

We consider a pullback square

\begin{CD}
P\times_M P' @>\overline{\pi}>> P' \\
@VV\overline{\pi'} V @VV\pi' V \\
P @>>\pi> M
\end{CD}

It is easy to see that $\overline{\pi'}\colon P\times_M P' \to P$ is an epimorphism with kernel $K'$ and $\overline{\pi}\colon P\times_M P' \to P'$ is an epimorphism with kernel $K$. You can check this yourself from the universal properties of kernels and pullbacks, or look up section 2.5 ("The pullback and pushout theorems") in [Freyd's "Abelian categories"](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/3/tr3.pdf). Note that pullback of an epimorphism is again an epimorphism, *because we work in an abelian category*.

So we have short exact sequences
$$0\to K' \to P\times_M P'\ \to P \to 0$$
and
$$0 \to K \to P\times_M P'\ \to P' \to 0$$
Both sequences split since $P$ and $P'$ are projective, hence
$$K'\oplus P \cong P\times_M P' \cong K\oplus P'.$$

Comment: $p'\in P' $may be written as $(\pi')^{-1}(m) +i'(k')$ for som $k\in K' $ and $m\in M.$ 
That is the key I need. I do this problem already because it is the 2.18 exercise in this book. However, I think it is just true for finite case. However, I am wrong. Thank you so much

Comment: @Lê Thế Long I added all the diagram chasing

Comment: @Lê Thế Long I added an alternative proof (something like the one in Wikipedia)

Comment: Just to mention it, the first proof scheme can also be adapted to any abelian category as follows: Consider a commutative diagram $$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}\ker f@>>>A@>f>> B@>>>0\\@VVV@VVgV@VVhV\\ \ker f'@>>i'>A'@>>f'> B'@>>>0\end{CD}$$ with exact rows, where $h$ is assumed to be an isomorphism and where the map between kernels is obtained from the universal property of $\ker f$. Then it is easy to check that the left square is cartesian; so we apply [08N2](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08N2). On the other hand, $g$ must be onto, whence $A\oplus \ker f'\xrightarrow{(g,i')}A'$ is onto.